# Sorting and categorise arraylist

Tags: java

I want to sort Arraylist based on the field 'code' like below and i want to add an additional record  into the current arraylist with the value by total price of same code.

```
No      Desc    Width      Height       Code        Price

1        WW     88.0        88.0      1021021       340.0       
4        TT     55.0        55.0      1021021       340.0       
5        PP     66.0        66.0      1021021       340.0   
2        gg     66.0        66.0      1021022       320.0       
3        LL     658.0       652.0     1021022       320.0
```

My expected output will be like this

```
1        WW     88.0        88.0      1021021       340.0       
4        TT     55.0        55.0      1021021       340.0       
5        PP     66.0        66.0      1021021       340.0
                                                    1020
2        gg     66.0        66.0      1021022       320.0       
3        LL     658.0       652.0     1021022       320.0
                                                    640
```

Any one who can suggest the best way to solve this problem?.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a class to represent your 'row' of data?

Answer (score 5):

If you were to use java, you can write your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass on the `ArrayList` and the comparator to the [`Collections.sort()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

From the Javadoc:

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort`) to allow precise control over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a natural ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with a `Comparator` example.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CodeComparator implements Comparator<Item> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item arg0, Item arg1) {
        return arg0.getCode().compareTo(arg1.getCode());
    }

}
```

And then sort your array with:

```
Collections.sort(itemList, new CodeComparator());
```